# How do I Access Files from one Ubuntu Partition on Another

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

A terminal error occured on my computer and I found myself unable to log in to Ubuntu. To remedy this, I decided to simply install it again on a partition and then access my saved files on the old partition from the new one, thereby losing only my software and settings. The problem is, I do not know how to retrieve those old files. There is an icon called "90 GB Filesystem" in Nautilus: it has 21 folders which hold which have exactly 1.7 GB of free space each and only system files in them.

The question here is: are my old saved files retrievable? Are they retrievable through "90 GB Filesystem" or some other means?

Answer (score 0):

Did you used separate partitions for your home folder? if you didn't:

- Mount the filesystem then Navigate through the filesystem to /home/your-user/ and search for the files copy them to a safe place.

If you did:

- Locate the correct partition and then Navigate through the partition and select your files and copy them to a safe place.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. There was no home/your-user/ in the Filesystem, so I guess I did use separate partitions. What do I use to navigate through the partition?

Comment: Do all partions show up in Nautilus?

Comment: There's nothing aside from the Filesystem, if that's what you're referring to. Otherwise, how would I navigate to the partition?
Also, it turns out there is a home/your-use/ folder; it contains a broken README and a broken link called Access-Your-Private-Data . desktop

Comment: Ah I see, this might be of Help to you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/71708/how-do-i-open-access-your-private-data-desktop

Comment: That answer says one has to log in to the directory that is encrypted. However, as I said before, that directory is so messed up that I cannot log in to it. It also says to use the command "ecryptfs-mount-private" but when I try the terminal says `The program 'ecryptfs-mount-private' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils`. When I do type that and enter my password, it only ever gets to 50%.